# FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found ')'

Tags: apex, lightning, debug-logs

We have issue with one of the apex class which stopping us from  configuring a record through lightning component. When we debugged the issue we found this error in debug logs and could not identify what is the issue related to.

Class:

```
public with sharing class customLookUpController {

 @AuraEnabled
public static List <sObject> fetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, String objectName, String queryFilterField, String fieldsToQuery) {  
    String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
    fieldsToQuery = fieldsToQuery != '' ? ', '+fieldsToQuery : fieldsToQuery;
    String sQuery = 'SELECT id, Name'+fieldsToQuery+' FROM '+objectName+' WHERE Name LIKE \''+searchKey+'\' '+queryFilterField+' ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 5';
    
    List<sObject> returnList = new List<sObject>();
    for (sObject obj : Database.query(sQuery)) returnList.add(obj);
    return returnList;
}


@AuraEnabled
public static List <sObject> fetchLookUpValues(String searchKeyWord, String objectName, String queryFilterField) {  
    String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
    String sQuery = 'SELECT id, Name FROM '+objectName+' WHERE Name LIKE \''+searchKey+'\' '+queryFilterField+' ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 5';
    
    List<sObject> returnList = new List<sObject>();
    for (sObject obj : Database.query(sQuery)) returnList.add(obj);
    return returnList;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List <sObject> fetchLookUpValuesNew(String searchKeyWord, String objectName, String queryFilterField, String fields, String queryConditions) {  
    String searchKey = searchKeyWord + '%';
    String sQuery;
    //String allfields = '';
    if(queryConditions != null && queryConditions != ''){
        sQuery = 'SELECT '+fields+' FROM '+objectName+' WHERE '+queryFilterField+' LIKE \''+searchKey+'\' '+' AND '+ queryConditions +' ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 10';
        System.debug('sQuery--'+sQuery);
    }
    else{
        sQuery = 'SELECT '+fields+' FROM '+objectName+' WHERE '+queryFilterField+' LIKE \''+searchKey+'\' '+' ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 10';
        System.debug('sQuery--'+sQuery);
    }     
    List<sObject> returnList = new List<sObject>();
    for (sObject obj : Database.query(sQuery)) returnList.add(obj);
    return returnList;
}
```

}

Error:

> Class.customLookUpController.fetchLookUpValues: line 10, column 1
> 08:11:59.0 (2330323)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found ')'

Debug log:

```
51.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,INFO;NBA,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
08:11:59.0 (163644)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|0052p000009sYJY|ramkumar.murugesan@lntinfotech.com-cte.uat|(GMT+01:00) Central European Standard Time (Europe/Paris)|GMT+01:00
08:11:59.0 (211455)|EXECUTION_STARTED
08:11:59.0 (217359)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|apex://customLookUpController/ACTION$fetchLookUpValues
08:11:59.0 (1287969)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p57000001MmYo|customLookUpController.fetchLookUpValues(String, String, String, String)
08:11:59.0 (2176405)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[10]|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found ')'
08:11:59.0 (2316403)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found ')'

Class.customLookUpController.fetchLookUpValues: line 10, column 1
08:11:59.0 (2330323)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found ')'

Class.customLookUpController.fetchLookUpValues: line 10, column 1
08:11:59.2 (2340395)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
08:11:59.2 (2340395)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
  Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
  Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
  Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
  Number of Publish Immediate DML: 0 out of 150
  Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
  Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
  Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
  Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
  Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
  Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

08:11:59.2 (2340395)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

08:11:59.0 (2370892)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|customLookUpController.fetchLookUpValues(String, String, String, String)
08:11:59.0 (2533470)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|apex://customLookUpController/ACTION$fetchLookUpValues
08:11:59.0 (2542518)|EXECUTION_FINISHED
```

Comment: Please debug searchKeyWord, objectName, queryFilterField and fieldsToQuery in the first fetchLookUpValues method where the error is happening.

Comment: Log the actual query string being executed. The problem will almost certainly become visible immediately.

Comment: @DavidReed I tried System.debug (sQuery); but the log did not provided me the query results.

Comment: Not the results, what is the _actual query_ that you are trying to execute that results in the exception being thrown.

Comment: @DavidReed Here is the query i received "SELECT id, Name, Multi_Temperature__c, Undermount__c, CC_Parent__c FROM SG_ProductBook__c WHERE Name LIKE '%' AND CC_Enabled__c=true AND (id IN ) OR CC_Parent__c IN )) ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 5"

Comment: Please [edit] to add this information to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in a comment, the actual query being executed is

```
SELECT id, Name, Multi_Temperature__c, Undermount__c, CC_Parent__c 
FROM SG_ProductBook__c 
WHERE Name LIKE '%' AND CC_Enabled__c=true AND (id IN ) OR CC_Parent__c IN )) 
ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 5
```

That immediately shows the problem:

> (id IN ) OR CC_Parent__c IN )

One of the strings you are templating in to build a `WHERE` clause is not valid SOQL.